# Why does \IEEEPARstart have conflict with \textcolor?

Tags: color, ieeetran, text-decorations, text-manipulation, ieee-style

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{
\IEEEPARstart{L}orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur elit lectus, lobortis at eros tincidunt, viverra cursus augue.}
\end{document}
```

### Result without `\textcolor`

[image: Without <code>\textcolor</code>]

### Result with `\textcolor`

[image: With <code>\textcolor</code>]

## Explanation & Questions:

As you may notice, normally the `\IEEEPARstart` letter will be aligned with the text, however, when the latter command is "affected" by the command `\textcolor` the letter will no longer be aligned, it will be *out of margin*.

- The first question, and please, if you are going to post an answer to
  this question, be sure to answer this and not only give a solution. Why does this happen?
- What is the solution to obtain colored text and aligned `\IEEEPARstart` letter?

Comment: `\textcolor` uses a group of its own and messes with the grouping in the definition of `\IEEEPARstart`. Try `\color{red}
\IEEEPARstart{L}{orem} ............. and then for black text put \color{black} text follows.`

Comment: I think that it works, could you posted as an answer?, please, and one more thing, are you sure it doesn't affect anything else (the `\color{}red`)? I'll see if I find any errors and tell you about it. And one more thing, do you know what is exactly the grouping definition that it's being changed? (Like to fix it in case I need to use specifically `\textcolor`)

Comment: @HarishKumar What if I had a different color before?, is there a way of saving the current color (like in a variable) each time before `\color{somecolor}` and then recall it?

Answer (score 3):

For all sorts of reasons it's best to start and end colour in horizontal mode, so I'd use `\textcolor` rather than `\color` also note that `\IEEEPARstart` takes two arguments not one, the intended usage is `\IEEEPARstart{L}{orem}` not `\IEEEPARstart{L}`.

Even though it means specifying the colour in more than one place I'd do the following, using a protected command to hide the colour name from the uppercasing which is applied to the second argument of `\IEEEPARstart`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{color}
\DeclareRobustCommand\red{\textcolor{red}}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\IEEEPARstart{\red{L}}{\red{orem}} \red{ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur elit lectus, lobortis at eros
  tincidunt, viverra cursus augue.}
\end{document}
```